# Dynamic header and footer template inclusion: footer script not included

Tags: templates, variables

I have a file that is being required by both the header and footer, and that file is meant to include the content for the footer or header dynamically.

So in my `header.php` and `footer php`, I only set a couple of variables, and include a common file, "include-cached-template":

```
<?php

$templatePath = get_template_directory() . '/templates/core-parts/footer-content.php';
$cacheId = 'footer';

require_once get_template_directory() . '/template-inclusion-handling/include-cached-template.php';
```

In `include-cached-template.php` I include the template that has the content for header or footer. I check that the dynamic variables are set, then do some cache check and require the template by the provided template path.
So it starts with:

```
<?php
// required variable: $templatePath
if(!isset($templatePath) || !isset($cacheId)){
    return;
}
```

EDIT: I did some debugging, where it seemed that the variables were still having the values for the header when the template to include the footer was loading. But it turns out that the template to load the footer was never included (as Tom Nowell points out below)

Comment: Can you explain the "inclusions" part using different words? I see that you are using `require_once` and you're not using WordPress template loading functions either. Why and how are you caching template files? Edit your question to add more information and answer the questions, right now things are very unclear and you're asking about a system that you've not explained or shared, though I strongly suspect you think that `require_once` will load the file multiple times, when actually it loads and runs it once and only once ( hence `require_once` ). It's also very weird to see basic HTML cached

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes, that was the problem! So if I use require, it works. Perhaps I should use "load_template() instead - good tip. You could add it as an answer . What about the caching of html - what is wrong with it? I cache the entire footer (which has php and html intertwined).

Comment: you should cache expensive things, HTML is the cheapest fastest thing PHP can generate, the act of caching it is more expensive/slower than generating it in the first place. It's better to cache individual queries/requests that are expensive, and to cache the data not the HTML so that they can be reused in multiple places even if the HTML is different

Comment: But if you have spaghetti code with queries baked in with the code, it can be hard to make caching logic for each individual thing, and the code may become even messier. I can understand if you have a clean template where the logic is collected outside of the template, then I guess you could cache all the stuff where that data is collected. But in this case, I don't see a better way than to cache all of it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the code uses `require_once` which only loads and runs the file once. `require` would fix the problem, but it would actually be better to use `get_template_part()` instead. This would allow you to use template filters, block templates, and child themes.

```php
get_template_part( string $slug, string $name = null, array $args = array() ): void|false
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/